# Python IDLE becomes slow on very large program input

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

Why does python idle become so slow when handling very large inputs, when the python command line does not?

For example, if I run "aman"*10000000 in python IDLE, it becomes unresponsive, but on python cmd line, it is quick.

Comment: `IDLE is intended to be a simple IDE and suitable for beginners` - that's it.

Comment: is cmd more better than idle in executing large inputs????

Comment: @AmanRastogi You've already tried so you should know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to research a bit. When I invoked idle on my machine, I saw another python process which uses `idlelib`

```
~$ ps -eaf | grep -in idle
234:1000     13122     1  5 16:44 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/idle-python2.7
235:1000     13124 13122  3 16:44 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python2.7 -c __import__('idlelib.run').run.main(True) 60839
239:1000     13146 12061  0 16:44 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -in idle
~$
```

The last parameter (60839) made me think. So I looked around for `idlelib` and got the implementation here https://github.com/pypy/pypy/blob/master/lib-python/2.7/idlelib/run.py#L49 The comment there says

```
Start the Python execution server in a subprocess

    In the Python subprocess, RPCServer is instantiated with handlerclass
    MyHandler, which inherits register/unregister methods from RPCHandler via
    the mix-in class SocketIO.
```

Now, things were clear to me. The IDLE sends commands to python interpreter over a TCP connection. Still, I am not convinced. Then I read the complete `Help`->`About IDLE`->`README`. It says

> IDLE executes Python code in a separate process, which is restarted
>   for each Run (F5) initiated from an editor window.  The environment
>   can also be  restarted from the Shell window without restarting IDLE.

**Conclusion**

When we have such a dependency (IDLE depending on response over a socket), the delay what you experienced is perfectly fine.